# Get empty tables when I restore .backup file to postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-restore

I have .backup file and i need to restore it to my postgres database.
But when i choose restore in my database and choose my file, i got all the tables with some empty tables. i don't know if i don't choose the right options but this is what i did :
I choose my backup file;
[image]

and then i choose this options from "Option1" and "Options2":[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this. Type the following command in the command prompt to restore the table:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_restore.exe -U user -p port -h host -w -Fc -d database-name < backup-file.backup
```